# Calling Javascript funct from PARENT

Tags: javascript, function, frame

There's tons of information on how to do the inverse of this, but I am trying to call a a function located in a child frame from the Parent.

I've tried ..

```
window.document.leftFrame.contentWindow.myfunct();

document.leftFrame.contentWindow.myfunct();

<frame ... onload="this.contentWindow.myfunct();">
```

No luck :/

What's the proper way to reference a child page/frame from the parent? Do I need to use an onload to make sure the js from the frame has loaded first? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `window.frames['frameName'].myfunct();`

Do note that this usually only works if the iframe is referring to a page on the same domain. Browsers restrict access to pages within frames that belong to a different domain for security reasons.

Comment: It is on the same domain. Idk why it wasn't working. I ended up solving it with by amending the url for the frame with a query string in the parent page, then using php and GET method to manually add the code to be executed. But since you're the only one to answer you get the points.